# how to extract certain columns of a file and save them in new file

Tags: bash, sed, awk, csh

I have a file which contains lines of data in the following format:

```
a11 a12 a13 a14 a15
a21 a22 a23 a24 a25 
a31 a32 a33 a34 a35 
a41 a42 a43 a44 a45 
.
.
.
```

what I need is to save this data in a new file with the following format after performing some arithmetic on it:

```
a11 
a12*x1 a13/y1 z1*a15+d1
a21 
a22*x2 a23/y2 z2*a25+d2
a31 
a32*x3 a33/y3 z3*a35+d3
.
.
.
.
```

all the xi, yi, zi and di are float numbers. These numbers are stored ina second file having the format:

```
x1 y1 z1 d1
x2 y2 z2 d2
x3 y3 z3 d3
.
.
.
```

I really appreciate it if you could please guide with a csh or bash snippet on how this can be done.

Cheers

Comment: It looks like a straight-forward enough `awk` script except your `x1`, `y1`, `d1`, aren't defined in this file. Where would they come from?

Comment: hi sarnold. they are floatig point numbers which are different for each row of data

Comment: @regex99 we need to know where you are getting the numbers from. Are you going to hand-code them in for each line? Are they stored in a second file? Are they the result of a function call?

Comment: @Kevin,It is from another file which has an array of x1 y1 z1 d1 x2 y2 z2 d2 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script (I call it `matmath`):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    factors = ARGV[1]
    ARGC--
}
{
    print $1
    getline line < factors
    split(line, f)
    print $2 * f[1], $3 / f[2], f[3] * $5 + f[4]
}
```

The data files:

matrix:

```
11 12 13 14 15
21 22 23 24 25
31 32 33 34 35
41 42 43 44 45
```

factors:

```
1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5
2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5
3.1 3.2 3.3 3.4 3.5
4.1 4.2 4.3 4.4 4.5
```

Example run:

```
$ chmod u+x matmath    # run once to set the script to be executable
$ ./matmath factors matrix
1.1
1.32 1.08333 3.35
2.1
4.62 1.04545 8.15
3.1
9.92 1.03125 14.95
4.1
17.22 1.02381 23.75
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) for that.

```
awk '{print $1; print $2 * x, $3 / y1, z1 * $5, ...}'
```

Essentially `$(a+b)` would result in the value in `a+b`th column.

Comment: hi mlt, I want the 1st column data to be in one line and the rest in a nother line immediately after that. and this operation to be done line-by-line. would the above awk one-liner do that?

Comment: `print` will add a newline. However I just noticed you have different x,y,z for each line...

Comment: An awkward workaround would be to merge 2 files on a line basis using awk's function [getline](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html) and then apply aforementioned line where x,y,z, are just columns past your main data. Do you really want to do it with shell and not something like Octave if you are performing some calculations???